# Compress html output from zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, output-buffering, html-manipulation

I'm currently using Zend Framework 2 beta for on PHP 5.4.4 to develop a personal webapp for self-study purpose.

I was wondering if it is possible to intercept the html output just before it is sent to the browser in order to minify it by removing all unnecessary white spaces.

How could I achieve this result in ZF2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, you can:

On Modle.php create an event that will trigger on finish

```
public function onBootstrap(Event $e)
{
    $app = $e->getTarget();
    $app->getEventManager()->attach('finish', array($this, 'doSomething'), 100);
}


public function doSomething ($e)
{
    $response = $e->getResponse();
    $content = $response->getBody();
    // do stuff here
    $response->setContent($content);

}
```

Comment: If my app is composed of many modules, on which module should I put this? the "main" module, or all of them? Anyway, I'll try this ASAP.

Comment: I put general events under Application. But it will work on any one of the modules

Answer (score 1):

Just put this two method inside any module.php . It will gzip and send compressed out put to the browser.

```
 public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->attach("finish", array($this, "compressOutput"), 100);
}

public function compressOutput($e)
    {
        $response = $e->getResponse();
        $content = $response->getBody();
        $content = preg_replace(array('/\>[^\S ]+/s', '/[^\S ]+\</s', '/(\s)+/s', '#(?://)?<![CDATA[(.*?)(?://)?]]>#s'), array('>', '<', '\\1', "//&lt;![CDATA[n" . '1' . "n//]]>"), $content);

        if (@strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip') !== false) {
            header('Content-Encoding: gzip');
            $content = gzencode($content, 9);
        }

        $response->setContent($content);
    }
```

Comment: A bit of explanation of this regex would help... currently it breaks any HTML.